# Mongooplog alternative

Tags: node.js, mongodb

As we all know that `mongooplog` tool is going to be removed in upcoming releases. I needed help about some the following issue:
I was planning to create a listener using `mongooplog` which will read any kind of activity on `mongodb` and will generate a trigger according to activity which will hit another server. Now, since `mongooplog` is going out, can anyone suggest what alternative can I use in this case and how to use it.

I got this warning when trying to use `mongooplog`. Please let me know if you any further questions.

> warning: mongooplog is deprecated, and will be removed completely in a future release

PS: I am using `node.js` framework to implement the listener. I have not written any code yet so have no code to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deprecation message you are quoting only refers to the `mongooplog` command-line tool, not the general approach of tailing the oplog. The `mongooplog` tool can be used for some types of data migrations, but isn't the right approach for a general purpose listener or to wrap in your Node.js application.

You should continue to [create a tailable cursor](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/) to follow oplog activity. Tailable cursors are supported directly by the MongoDB drivers. For an example using Node.js see: [The MongoDB Oplog & Node.js](https://www.compose.io/articles/the-mongodb-oplog-and-node-js/).

You may also want to watch/upvote [SERVER-13932: Change Notification Stream API](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13932) in the MongoDB issue tracker, which is a feature suggestion for a formal API (rather than relying on the internal oplog format used by replication).